# Can the "Gatling" be countered by "Missed!"?

Tags: bang

The following rules are taken from English manual of Italian version of *Bang! The Bullet!*.

Regarding the card *Missed!* the interesting part is:

> If you are hit by a *BANG!* you may immediately play a *Missed!* - even tough it is not your turn! - to cancel the shot. [...]

Regarding the card *Gatling!* the interesting part is the note:

> The symbols show "a BANG!" to "all the other players". **Note:** even though the *Gatling* shoots a *BANG!* to all the other players, it is **not** considered a *BANG!* **card**.

This note makes me wondering if the *Gatling* can be countered by a *Missed!* or not. Reading the rules I think that the *Gatling* cannot be countered but in this case the card is too overpowered.

Note that also other characters and cards are influenced by how we interpret the *Gatling* card.

e.g. These characters of the base game are influenced:

- *Calamity Janet*: she could use *BANG!* as missed
- *Jourdonnais*: he can *draw!* when he is target of a *BANG!*
- *Slab the Killer*: players trying to cancel his *BANG!* cards need to play 2 *Missed!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the FAQ [here](http://www.dvgiochi.net/bang/bang_faq_eng.pdf) the following question and answer says,

> Q19. How many Missed! cards are required to cancel a Gatling played by Slab the Killer?
>
> A. Only one. The special ability of Slab the Killer applies to BANG! cards only.

For reference Slab's ability is "Players trying to cancel his BANG! cards need to play 2 Missed!"

This would infer to me that a Missed card can be used against a gattling as the question says that one card is needed to stop it.

There is also [This](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/1439259/missed) thread on BGG which goes into detail saying a Miss can be played.  It makes the distinction between a bang card and a bang action so whilst you can only play one Bang card you can play multiple cards with bang actions and any bang action can be missed.

Comment: Thanks, the difference between _BANG!_ actions and _BANG!_ cards clean all doubts even for further cards.